# What is difference between template <typename T> and template <class T>. For me both are generating the same result

Tags: c++, templates

What is difference between `template <typename T>`  and `template <class T>`.
For me both are generating the same result.

for example

```
template <class T>
T Average(T *atArray, int nNumValues)
{
    T tSum = 0;
    for (int nCount=0; nCount < nNumValues; nCount++)
        tSum += atArray[nCount];

    tSum /= nNumValues;
    return tSum;
}
```

if I change it to  `template <typename T>` it's the same

Answer (score 71, accepted):

There is no difference.  `typename` and `class` are interchangeable in the declaration of a type template parameter.

You do, however, have to use `class` (and not `typename`) when declaring a template template parameter:

```
template <template <typename> class    T> class C { }; // valid!
template <template <typename> typename T> class C { }; // invalid!  o noez!
```

Comment: @James: I got bitten by that one, do you know if there is any rationale behind the invalid use of `typename` in that situation ? I thought that the idea of `typename` was to reserve `class` to the declaration / definition of new classes.

Comment: @Matthieu: I don't think there is a rational, it just happened. Someone wanted to write `template<typename T>` instead of `template<class T>`when T isn't a class. And he got a "Why not!" response! Everywhere else, class and typename are still different.

Comment: @Matthiew M. If you look closely at it, it does look like a class declaration (well, a class template declaration). And in the same way that when declaring a class template you are required to use `class` (or `struct`) for the actual type (!= arguments), you are required to do it here. I find it at the very least consistent.

Comment: @David: Ah! I can see you rationale, it makes sense somewhat.

Comment: Note that as of C++17, barring any last-minute changes, `template<typename> typename` will become valid.

Answer (score 7):

They're equivalent and interchangeable for most of the times, and some prefer typename because using the keyword class in that context seems confusing.

The reason why typename is needed is for those ambiguous cases when using `template <class T>`  for example, you define a template like this:

```
template <class T>
void MyMethod() {
   T::iterator * var;
}
```

and then for some reason the user of your template decides to instantiate the class as this

```
class TestObject {
   static int iterator; //ambiguous
};

MyMethod<TestObject>(); //error
```

It becomes ambiguous what var should be, an instance of a class iterator or the static type int. So for this cases typename was introduced to force the template object to be interpreted as a type.

Answer (score 2):

Look at this:

http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/8027/

They both produce the same behaviour. When you use typename its more readable.